# SELECT em duas tabelas, com ID separados por vírgula

Tags: php, mysqli, select

Olá! Como fazer um SELECT que retorne os dados da primeira tabela, cujos "id" estão separados por vírgulas na segunda tabela? Exemplo:

```
tbl_cores
    id | cor
    1  | azul
    2  | verde
    3  | amarelo
    4  | vermelho

tbl_mesa
    id | cores
    1  | 2,4
    2  | 1,3
    3  | 2,3,4,1
```

===========
Preciso que retorne:

```
1 = verde vermelho
2 = azul amarelo
3 = verde amarelo vermelho azul
```

Obrigado por qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Queres dizer que a coluna cores é to tipo string/varchar?

Comment: Você quer o id da tabela tbl_cores for = 1 ele retorne as cores 2,4 da tabela tbl_mesa. a comparação dessas tabelas são os próprios ids?

Comment: sim, varchar...

Comment: A tbl_mesa traz os ID da tbl_cores. Obrigado por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Tentei ajudar, acho que assim dá

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso, você pode criar uma *FUNCTION* que retorne uma string com o nome das cores passando os *IDS* que você quer, da seguinte forma.

```
create FUNCTION StringListToTexto
(
    @List varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @item varchar(800), @Pos int

    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)

    declare @texto varchar(max) = '';

     ---- sua tabela substituar por sua tabela
    declare @tbl_coresAux TABLE (id INT, cor VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO @tbl_coresAux VALUES 
    (1  ,' azul'),
    (2  ,' verde'),
    (3  ,' amarelo'),
    (4  ,' vermelho')
    -----

    WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @item = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@List, @Pos - 1)))
        IF @item <> ''
        BEGIN
            declare @IdAux int = (CAST(@item AS int));

            set @texto = @texto +  (Select cor from @tbl_coresAux where id = @IdAux);
        END
        SET @List = RIGHT(@List, LEN(@List) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)
    END

    RETURN @texto
END
```

E você chamaria da seguinte forma.

```
declare @tbl_cores TABLE (id INT, cor VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @tbl_cores VALUES 
(1  ,' azul'),
(2  ,' verde'),
(3  ,' amarelo'),
(4  ,' vermelho')

declare @tbl_mesa TABLE (id INT, cores VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @tbl_mesa VALUES 
(1  ,'2,4'),
(2  ,'1,3'),
(3  ,'2,3,4,1')



select id, ([dbo].[StringListToTexto] (cores)) from @tbl_mesa
where id = 2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

O ideal mesmo, caso você tenha acesso e possa alterar a estrutura desse banco, seria utilizar de uma relação muitos para muitos. Dessa forma você poderia mapear corretamente, segundo as formas normais, e não teria problemas ao fazer o select nas tabelas. Por exemplo:

```
tbl_cores
    id | cor
    1  | azul
    2  | verde
    3  | amarelo
    4  | vermelho

tbl_mesa_cores
    id | id_mesa | id_cores
    1  | 1       | 2
    2  | 1       | 4
    3  | 2       | 1
    4  | 2       | 3
    5  | 3       | 2
    6  | 3       | 3
    7  | 3       | 4
    8  | 3       | 1

tbl_mesa
    id | desc
    1  | -
    2  | -
    3  | -
```

Comment: Seria uma boa pratica. +1;

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
select tbl_mesa.id, tbl_cores.cor 
from tbl_mesa inner join tbl_cores
       on ',' + tbl_mesa.cores + ',' like '%,' + cast(tbl_cores.id as nvarchar(20)) + ',%'
```